# Is there any alternatives in useState when calling multipleStates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

So I don't really have a problem but I'm troubling with a lot of codes and I want to reduce it.

So for example I have

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Source() {

    const [addClockName,setAddClockName] = useState("Add Clock Name")
    const [addTime,setAddTime] = useState("Time")
    const [addMusic,setAddMusic] = useState("Music")
    const [addAlarmlength,setAddAlarmlength] = useState("Alarm length")

    return [
        addClockName,setAddClockName,
        addTime,setAddTime,
        addMusic,setAddMusic,
        addAlarmlength,setAddAlarmlength
    ]
}

export default Source
```

When I'm importing this it will be something like this in other files

```
import Source from 'path'

    const [
        addClockName,setAddClockName,
        addTime,setAddTime,
        addMusic,setAddMusic,
        addAlarmlength,setAddAlarmlength
    ] = Source()

    instead like this 
    const { addTime } = Source() 
    
    ...or whatsoever
```

but what I only want to import is just certain items that I need and I want to avoid recalling the same array of items. Is there any alternatives or just a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return an array, return an object. Then you can pick only the properties of the object that you want. Since it's a custom hook, you should also probably prefix it with `use`.

```
const useSource = () => {
    // ...
    return {
        addClockName, setAddClockName,
        addTime, setAddTime,
        addMusic, setAddMusic,
        addAlarmlength, setAddAlarmlength
    };
```

and, for example, if you only want to use the music state:

```
const {
    addMusic,
    setAddMusic,
} = useSource()
```

But keep in mind that if you do this, you'll have separate states *every time you call* `useSource`, which may not be desirable. If you want to have just one full Source state, call it once, then pass down the result so that children can pick what they want to use, like:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const sourceObj = useSource();
    // ...
    return <SomeComponent sourceObj={sourceObj}>
}
const SomeComponent = ({ sourceObj }) => {
    const { addMusic, setAddMusic } = sourceObj;
    // ...
```

Comment: I have another question when I'm trying to pass it in different multiple files..does it change though too or not

Comment: If you want your app to have just one set of states relating to Source (and not, for example, one `addTime` related to one call, and another `addTime` related to another), then you should call `useSource` just once, in a parent component, and pass down the object to children, as in the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry
You can make your own hooks and use it.
Example:
Make custom hooks

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  }, [url]);

  return [data];
};

export default useFetch;
```

and use it:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [data] = useFetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");

  return (
    <>
      {data &&
        data.map((item) => {
          return <p key={item.id}>{item.title}</p>;
        })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Good luck..